# How to press/tap likebutton widget using a iconbutton widget

Tags: flutter

how can one remove the like on the likebutton widget(from the like_button package) by pressing an iconbutton widget?

I tried this by way of attaching a Global key to the likebutton widget, and within the onpress callback of the iconbutton i have the below code. The globalkey is within the mybuttonkey variable.

```
`   RenderBox renderbox = mybuttonkey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset position = renderbox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    double x = position.dx;
    double y = position.dy;


    GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerDownEvent(
    position: Offset(x, y),
    )); //trigger button up,

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    //add delay between up and down button

    GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(PointerUpEvent(position: Offset(x, y),)); //trigger        button down`type here
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove a like from the `LikeButton` widget is to pass a value to the `isLiked` parameter, and have another button that also uses that value.

Here's an example of a working Flutter app that has a `LikeButton` and an `IconButton` that can reset it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: MainPage());
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool isLiked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              LikeButton(isLiked: isLiked),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: setState(() => isLiked = false),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Clicking the `IconButton` will "un-like" the `LikeButton`. Feel free to let me know if you were trying to do something else.

Comment: but the animation for likeButton is not triggered by this approach